# how to keep the session active even i opened in multiple tabs in same browser

Tags: javascript, php, session

i would like to implement one thing.i opened my site in multiple tabs. while i work in one tab others tabs should not be timedout. it should be alive. how to keep alive for other tabs. i used below js to find idle time logout.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
})

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 2) { // 30 minutes

        var beforeTime = new Date()
        var bminutes = beforeTime.getMinutes();
        var bseconds = beforeTime.getSeconds(); 
        var user='<?php echo Auth::getSessionUserFullName();?>';
        if(user!='')
        {
            var timehours=beforeTime.getHours();
            var timeoutmin=bminutes+1;
            var timeoutseconds=bseconds-1;
            if(timeoutseconds>59)
            {
                timeoutseconds=0;
                timeoutmin=timeoutmin+1;
            }
            if(timeoutmin>59)
            {
                timeoutmin=0;
                timehours=hours+1;

            }
            if(timehours>24)
            {
                timehours=0;
            }
          var ok=confirm("Your session  expire time started at "+beforeTime.getHours()+":"+beforeTime.getMinutes()+":"+beforeTime.getSeconds()+".Please click 'OK' before "+timehours+":"+timeoutmin+":"+timeoutseconds+" to stay signed in.");
        if(ok)
        {
            var currentTime = new Date()
            var aminutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var aseconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
            var time=aminutes-bminutes;
            if(aminutes>bminutes && aseconds>bseconds)
            {
                alert('Time out!!Please login again to access.');
                window.location.href='<? echo APPLICATION_WEBROOT?>auth/logout';
                return false;
            }
            else if(time>=2)
            {
                alert('Time out!!Please login again to access.');
                window.location.href='<? echo APPLICATION_WEBROOT?>auth/logout';
                return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            window.location.href='<? echo APPLICATION_WEBROOT?>auth/logout';
        }
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Please help me. how to keep the sessions for all opened tabs.thanks in advance

Comment: If you implement timeouts like this (which is itself a questionable choice) then you simply can't. A browser tab doesn't know about other browser tabs.

Comment: ok. how can i implement while i removed js.

Answer (score 0):

The session is not tab specific. It is for the whole browser instance.

The session is extended when a user makes a request to the server. So depending on your application, you may have to generate regular requests to the server to extend that session.

For that, you can use the setInterval javascript function to trigger an AJAX call to your PHP backend.

Hope that helps...

BTW: be careful because some browsers do deactivate the tabs which don't have the user focus (Chrome for example) - it will not modify session... but some JS could be suspended.

Comment: Actually the session is usually implemented as a Cookie sent in each request from the client to the server. Then the server answers with a new Cookie with a new expiration date.

When the expiration date is in the past, the Cookie is not sent and the session is therefore closed...

Comment: Why don't you put the expiration time of the session big enough to not expire and not require to send ajax request to server to renew the session? However sending requests will cause load server side, I think the better solution is to extend the timeout to be reasonable for your purpopse.

Comment: @ArdiGoxhaj Well, sending a request to the server every 5 minutes is not gonna overload your server (especially since the action you call should not be CPU expensive). Having a longer timeout may solve the problem for simple pages, but it is not sufficient for web applications. Users will be pretty annoyed when they lose their work because the session has expired (Have you already lost the e-mail you were writing on a webmail, how did you feel?).

Comment: Performing requests loads the server as long as a new thread will be created for each request. And why it is not sufficient for web applications? You extend the session everytime you connect to the server, I think this is the best approach instead sending requests...

Comment: Well, this "a new thread will be created for each request" is not true, it might be true for some servers, but most are only reusing a pool of threads or even some are handling request like Events (Nginx, Node.js, Netty based). 

And some web applications may not naturally do requests to the server. For example if you play a game written in JS, write an article in a wiki, etc. I was just talking about working solutions to extend a session. Not solutions that will eventually break.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way I can think of is handle the session yourself in the server.

Here's a system that might work (welcome suggestions of improvement):

1) store your own custom session in server DB, with IP being the unique identifier.

2) whenever user interacts with your server, grab its IP and update the corresponding session stored in server. If that session has already timeout, redirect user to timeout page.

there might be many things that I haven't though through, but in my mind this should be a viable way to maintain session across tabs