# after session is expried, the whole web renders in different way after I call an ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf, session-timeout, expired-sessions

I meet a problem like this.

My web run correctly until I open 2 tabs (in the same browser). In both tabs, I log in to my web. After that, I log out in one tab, in the other tab, I call an ajax request and it returns me to login page. I log in again in that tab and my home page render every things, every dialogue, every element without calling it.

I am using the spring, jsf and spring web flow for this project.

Comment: did you debug the program

Comment: yes, i've already debug and add this 

HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
        // Clear old session request cache to prevent ViewExpiredException
        requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);

but still not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754993/how-to-keep-the-session-active-even-i-opened-in-multiple-tabs-in-same-browser

Comment: When you face a problem in client side which you couldn't explain, always press F12 in webbrowser and explore JS console and HTTP traffic monitor for clues. See also "Information to provide when asking JSF questions" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info Include this information in your question.